# Intellij: svn diff shows all lines changed when deleting one line, CRLF not changed

Tags: intellij-idea, eol

A yaml is generated by gradle task on windows. When the file is opened in Intellij editor, it shows CRLF as line separator.

Delete one line, then save.

It still shows CRLF as line separator. But

```
 svn diff
```

shows all lines are changed

```
 svn diff -x --ignore-eol-style
```

Shows one line deleted (expected).

How to keep line separator? No .editorConfig files.

Intellij version: 2022.3.2.